# Selling tickets using WordPress + WPML + WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wpml

I have specific (technical + process) issue on one e-commerce project.
We have fully active and working WordPress + WooCommerce, internationalized with premium WPML plugin (everything setup) + Events plugin for events.

We tried to find premium plugin for selling tickets over WooCommerce, but none of the solutions seems to be WPML complient. Events plugin (create by Modern Tribe) have Event Tickets Plus plugin but it doesn't support WPML (it doesn't work).

Does anyone have idea for a good premium plugin to do this, or some patch or workaround for this business process?

**So ticket buying process is somewhat like this:**

*Read text -> choose ticket type (can be several tickets of different types) -> register people for each ticket – custom fields for every ticket type (or skip this by clicking a button and register later) -> pay (chose payment option and pay for the ticket)*

Ideas? :)

Comment: May be you have not try [**this WPML trick**](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/wpml-51) for **Event Tickets Plus**. You will find a kind of user guide on this thread link (at the end). If this doesn't work, you may need to alter some code on **Event Tickets Plus**  plugin, to have all needed terms translatable for WPML.

Comment: Could you give me more information about this? I read that post, but I weren't able to solve my problem. Did you have any particular solution in mind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Original issue wasn't related to translations, but to fact that Events plugin from Tribe is not working with WPML (it crashes). That is later confirmed by Tribe (plugin creators) and WPML translations aren't a way to fix this.

Anyway, after several days we managed to find a good workaround. I'll describe it here, in case anyone has the same issue (I noticed people are complaining about Event Tickets from Tribe aren't supporting WPML.

So, we did this:

1. We kept original Event plugin (free version)
2. We removed Event Ticket and Event Ticket Plus plugins (we don't use
   them)
3. We decided to **simulate different Tickets with Product variations**
   There is *category called Ticket*. Product is now ticket for one specific event, and each variation is
   type for that ticket.
4. We created **separated template for category for Ticket** where we
   removed all WooCommerce things that we don't need for ticket.
5. We purchased **plugin for presenting variations in table view**
   and customized it according to our needs.

Now, we have all functionalities that we needed without Tickets plugin from Tribe, everything is WPML ready and we have possibility to customize it even more according to our Use Cases.

Example of our implementation can be found at link:
http://cashflowtallinn.ee/ru/event/vvedenie-v-rynok-tsennyh-bumag-i-optsionov-june2016/

[image]

Comment: can we use different products as different type of 1 event? so that we dont have to purchase variations in table view ?